# How do I find the position of matching parentheses or braces in a given piece of text?

Tags: algorithm

A lot of text editors and IDEs have a feature that highlights matching parentheses, square brackets, or curly braces when the cursor is placed over either the opening or closing character in one of these pairs.

What algorithm is used to find the position of the matching parenthesis, given the position of either an opening or closing parenthesis in a text file?  Keep in mind that these characters can be nested, so simply scanning forward or backward through the text until you find the opposite character is insufficient.

**Example:**

I recently ran into this problem when writing a [Brainf*ck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) interpreter in Java.  `[` and `]` in that language are analogous to a while loop, and can be nested.  The interpreter needs to find the matching `[` or `]` depending on the value at the data pointer.  See the [ROT13 example code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck#ROT13) for an illustration of nesting.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Given the position of an open parenthesis in an array of characters, there's a simple algorithm that uses a counter to find the matching close parenthesis.

- Initialize a counter to 1.
- Loop forward (to the right) through the text.

  - If another open parenthesis is encountered, increment the counter.
  - If a closing parenthesis is encountered, decrement the counter.
- When the counter reaches zero, you've found the matching closing parenthesis.

In code this looks something like:

```java
public int findClosingParen(char[] text, int openPos) {
    int closePos = openPos;
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter > 0) {
        char c = text[++closePos];
        if (c == '(') {
            counter++;
        }
        else if (c == ')') {
            counter--;
        }
    }
    return closePos;
}
```

The algorithm for finding the position of the matching open parenthesis given a closing parenthesis is the opposite.

- Initialize a counter to 1.
- Loop backwards (to the left) through the text.

  - If an open parenthesis is encountered, decrement the counter.
  - If a closing parenthesis is encountered, increment the counter.
- When the counter reaches zero, you've found the matching open parenthesis.

In code:

```java
public int findOpenParen(char[] text, int closePos) {
    int openPos = closePos;
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter > 0) {
        char c = text[--openPos];
        if (c == '(') {
            counter--;
        }
        else if (c == ')') {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return openPos;
}
```

**Note:** Both of the examples above assume that parentheses are balanced, so no array bounds checking is done.  A real implementation would check that you don't run off the end of the array, and throw an exception (or return an error code) that indicates that parentheses are unbalanced in the input text if you do.

Comment: This is a great function Bill.  It goes around an infinite loop if there is no matching bracket, however.

Easily fixed:

public int findClosingParen(char[] text, int openPos) {
    int closePos = openPos;
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter > 0) {
        char c = text[++closePos];
        if (c == '(') {
            counter++;
        }
        else if (c == ')') {
            counter--;
        }
    }
    return closePos;
}

Comment: Good question, great answer, and just what I needed.  You're *both* getting +1's. The two of you should hang out sometime; I bet you'd get along.

Comment: You need to break the loop if there are no parenthesis because you will get infinite loop

Comment: Also don't forget to ignore string literals as well if your language supports them as they can contain an unbalanced amount of brackets.

Comment: | The two of you should hang out sometime; I bet you'd get along.


Answer (score 0):

This code expects the incoming string will have even number of characters and they are just brackets, as per the one of the code challenges online.

```java
public class Brackets {

    public int checkForNestedBrackets(String S) {

        String left  = "[{("; // Maintain matching brackets will have same index
        String right = "]})";

        int length = S.length();
        int count = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (left.indexOf(S.charAt(i)) == right.indexOf(S.charAt(length - i - 1))) {
                count++;
                if (i == (length / 2) - 1)  // Break loop when you reach midway
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (count == length / 2) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s1 = "{[()()]}";
        String s2 = "([)()]";

        System.out.println(new Brackets().checkForNestedBrackets(s1));
        System.out.println(new Brackets().checkForNestedBrackets(s2));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The use of a stack is very simple and effective. Each time you come across an opening parenthesis, you put it in the stack (the index of the parenthesis). As soon as you come across a closing parenthesis, the inside of the opening parenthesis is at the top of the stack, then remove it from the stack and so on. Here is a small example in C++.

```cpp
void exemple(string inputString) {
    stack<int> openIndices;

    for (int i = 0; i < inputString.size(); i++) {
        if (inputString[i] == '(') {
            openIndices.push(i);
        }
        else if (inputString[i] == ')') {
            if (!openIndices.empty()) {
                int openIndex = openIndices.top();
                openIndices.pop();
                // Do what you want
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```java
private String GetJsonFromString(String source, String tagName)
{
    int tagIndex = source.IndexOf(tagName);
    if (tagIndex < 0)
        return "";
    string rightSource = source.Substring(tagIndex).Trim();

    int openBrackeIndex = rightSource.IndexOf("{");
    if (openBrackeIndex < 0)
        return "";
    rightSource = rightSource.Substring(openBrackeIndex).Trim();

    int closePos = 0;
    int counter = 1;
    while (counter > 0)
    {
        char c = rightSource.ToCharArray()[++closePos];
        if (c == '{')
        {
            counter++;
        }
        else if (c == '}')
        {
            counter--;
        }
    }
    return rightSource.Substring(0, closePos + 1);
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55026354/edit), not here in comments (*** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).