# Getting 'begin' and 'end' of blocks in a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, text-parsing

I'm trying to make a function to get the beginning and end of part of a string similar to a [code block](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_(programming)), returning the corresponding character index.
Example:

```
abc [ //A0 - start
   def [ //B1 - start
      ghi [ //C2 - start
         jkl
      ] //D2 - end
   ] //E1 - end
] //F0 - end
```

then a *getBlock* function would receive the string and index of one of the characters ("[" or "]") and return the index of its corresponding partner:

```
var str = "abc [def [ghi [jkl]]]";

getBlock(str, 4); // returns 20 ("F0" in the example)
getBlock(str, 9); // returns 19 ("E1")
getBlock(str, 14); // returns 18 ("D2")
getBlock(str, 20); // returns 4 ("A0")
getBlock(str, 19); // returns 9 ("B1")
getBlock(str, 18); // returns 14 ("C2")
```

This is my functional attempt so far:

```js
function getBlock(str) {
    console.log({
        "start": Array.from(str.matchAll(/\[/g)).map(m => m.index),
        "end": Array.from(str.matchAll(/\]/g)).map(m => m.index)
    })
}
getBlock("abc [def [ghi [jkl]]]")
```

It returns two arrays containing the index of all start and end characters, but I still haven't been able to figure out a logic to get its partners individually, any idea if that's possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find the position of matching parentheses or braces in a given piece of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752225/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-matching-parentheses-or-braces-in-a-given-piece-of)

Comment: @HereticMonkey indeed, it seems to be the same question, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have a solution in JavaScript, although the answer suggests an algorithm. I just posted the JavaScript solution I found, probably not the best one, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I ended up creating a somewhat ugly solution, but it seems to work as expected:

```
function getBlock(str, i) {
    var blocks = Array.from(str.matchAll(/\[|]/g)).map(m => m.index);
    return blocks[(blocks.length-blocks.indexOf(i))-1];
}

// must return 20 19 18 4 9 14
var str = "abc [def [ghi [jkl]]]";
console.log(
  getBlock(str, 4),
  getBlock(str, 9),
  getBlock(str, 14),
  getBlock(str, 20),
  getBlock(str, 19),
  getBlock(str, 18)
);
```

the logic is very simple, instead of returning two arrays it returns only one:

```
[4, 9, 14, 18, 19, 20]
```

from there you just need to get the values ​​from the "middle":

```
    14 18
  9      19
4          20
```

and that's it.

Edit:
It works for the case where each block has only one block inside it, but if there are two blocks side by side it doesn't.
Example where it fails:

```
var str = "abc [def] [ghi]";
getBlock(str, 10) // returns 8 instead of 14
```

Edit 2 (**Solution**):

Okay this should be the proper JavaScript solution, inspired by @HereticMonkey's comment regarding [How do I find the position of matching parentheses or braces in a given piece of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12752225/how-do-i-find-the-position-of-matching-parentheses-or-braces-in-a-given-piece-of), the only difference is that this version is in JavaScript and has been slightly changed to allow start and end indexes.

```js
function getBlock(str, start) {
  var end = start;
  var counter = 1;
  while (counter > 0) {
    var direction = (symbol) => ((str[start] == symbol) ? 1 : -1);
    var char = str[end += direction("[")];
    if (char == "[" || char == "]") {
      counter += direction(char)
    };
  }
  return {
    "start": start,
    "end": end
  };
}

var str = "abc [def [ijk]] [ghi]";
console.log(
  getBlock(str, 4), // {start: 4, end: 14}
  getBlock(str, 9), // {start: 9, end: 13}
  getBlock(str, 16) // {start: 16, end: 20}
);
```